# Cant find gn or autoninja for chromium development

Tags: chromium

I have previously followed a tutorial on setting up chromium development for mac from [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/mac_build_instructions.md). I had this all working. I then restarted my machine but now I can't use `gn` or `autoninja` I get the following errors

`zsh: command not found: gn`

`zsh: command not found: autoninja`

I have checked my path and setup it up again using the find_depot_tools.py script and it shows as being correctly setup. I'm not totally sure what I can do to fix this or why it has even happened. If anyone could shed some light on this I would be very grateful.

Perhaps the easiest thing would be to reinstall these, but I'm not totally sure how to do this as they are both chrome specific tools as far as I can tell.

Comment: Have you setup environment variables as it is required in the manual?

Comment: Yes I said I have checked my path and set it up again using find_depot_tools.py which also confirms it is there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by running the command in the command in chromium/src and ensuring my path was correctly set.